# How to warp an image in python?

Tags: python, image-processing

How do i transform the image to make **warp effect** using pull warp like in the below image?

Left image is the input and right one is the output (warped version)

I read this article [Image warping](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/application_development/9781785283932/1/ch01lvl1sec16/image-warping) and found some hint. Now my question is that how do i calculate the offset ?

[image]

Comment: Questions that ask "please help me" tend to be looking for highly localized guidance, or in some cases, ongoing or private assistance, which is not suited to our Q&A format. It is also rather vague, and is better replaced with a more specific question. Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Comment: The best thing is to do some research on the topic yourself, find two or three, _analyze_ them, determine if they work for you or not, and _try them out_. Come to us when you have a specific question about something you have attempted to do and show your [mcve] and where you are stuck at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like mission for [scipy.ndimage.geometric_transform](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.geometric_transform.html).
Consider following example, using

```
1 2
3 4
```

as input 2D array

```
t = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]],dtype='uint8') #our input array
def func(x):
    return (x[1],x[0])
out = scipy.ndimage.geometric_transform(t,func)
print(out)
```

output:

```
[[1 3]
 [2 4]]
```

So what happend? For each cell in input, `func` with that cell position (tuple) as argument is calculated and its output used as new location for cell, remembering that indexes are starting at 0 and they are in y,x manner:

- 1 position is 0,0
- 2 position is 0,1
- 3 position is 1,0
- 4 position is 1,1

My example function simply switch y with x so

- 1 new position is 0,0
- 2 new position is 1,0
- 3 new position is 0,1
- 4 new position is 1,1

which indeed you could see in output.

Using `cv2.imread` function you can easily read image into numpy array, if you want solely transform grayscale image thats make things simpler as you would deal with 2D array rather than 3D array. Remember to use        `cv2.imread('someimage.bmp',0)` (with `0` as second argument) when loading grayscale image.

Main challenge is creating the function: assuming grayscale its input is 2-tuple - position of "donor" pixel and output is 2-tuple - position of "recipient", note that this function do not have to cover whole output area - in case of output pixel missing "donor" it is interpolated.